# EXCEL: Getting a range of cells to always total 100%, even if new percentages are added or taken away (other cells update)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic

I am trying for an Excel formula that will perform the following: I have a series of rows that hold percentages (e.g. total % of business by account), and a sum row which, of course, equals 100%. I am trying to make this dynamic. So, for example, I add 5% to one of the cells where there was 0%, and the distribution changes in the other cells in the range to still equal 100%. Like, slicing the pie differently and always getting to 100%. Thanks for any assistance!

My experience level with Excel is better than most, but limited. To frame it for the pros, I can peform lookups, ifs, countifs, that level of stuff. So, I started looking online and stumbled into a few things I found  with MMULT, SEQUENCE, OFFSET, COUNTIF... they're not doing what I'm asking though. It's possilbel I don't know the name or phrase for what it is I am looking to do for my staff, and that is dead-ending me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Please post some sample data and your expected result. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: There are two easy solutions that come to mind;  1)  Absorb the remainder into one (i.e. the last) category, with a formula like `=1 - sum(range of other categories)`
2) Apply scaling, i.e. divide each nr by the sum, so the sum of the new nrs is 1.

Comment: Hey, so I ended up using this and tying it to a 100%  (I23) Cell:

=IF([@[Formula Cell]]<>"",0,I3/$I$23)